# C++: Pass a struct to a function

Tags: c++, function, struct, parameter-passing

Here is what I am doing:

A struct is defined in the single.h file:

```
typedef struct
{
    double x,y,z;
}PhysicalSize;
```

This struct is used in single.cpp file

```
PhysicalSize physicalSize;
physicalSize.x = xstageStepSize;
physicalSize.y = ystageStepSize;
physicalSize.z = zstageStepSize;

long SaveTIFFWithOME(wchar_t *filePathAndName, char * pMemoryBuffer, long width, long height, unsigned short * rlut, unsigned short * glut,unsigned short * blut,
                 double umPerPixel,int nc, int nt, int nz, double timeIncrement, int c, int t, int z,string * acquiredDateTime,double deltaT, 
                 string * omeTiffData, AcquireSingle::PhysicalSize physicalSize)
```

I stepped through the function, and it seems fine that all `physicalSize.x, physicalSize.y and physicalSize.z` got right value. However, when I step `SaveTIFFWithOME()`, all `physicalSize.x, physicalSize.y and physicalSize.z` look wierd as if they are never initialized.

I am wondering where I did wrong, and what is the right way to pass a struct, as an argument, to a function? Thanks.

Comment: Show us inside `SaveTIFFWithOME`.

Comment: @DieterLücking: It's completely valid C++. It's not very idiomatic, though.

Comment: Though it is a c struct, not a c++ struct; an important difference

Comment: @Paranaix: Huh? What is "a C struct" in C++?

Comment: Exactly the thing above AFAIK, no constructors, destructors etc. Just a "plain memory" structure

Comment: @Paranaix Then you meant a POD struct, not "C" struct.

Comment: @Paranaix: No, sorry but that's nonsense. The OP is writing C++, so his `struct` supports the whole range of class features. Only in C are `struct`s so limited, but the OP is neither writing nor compiling C.

Comment: Ok seems that I have missunderstood something then

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code above.

**You're passing the structure just fine!**

Either `SaveTIFFWithOME` is broken (possible overrun of those buffer arguments?) or you're misinterpreting your results.

Comment: You are right. When I watch the value of physicalSize in my code under debugging mode, it shows weird numbers. However, when running the program without debugging, the correct results just save in the xml files. I have no idea how this is happening. I mean did I actually see what saw? I don't have an explanation, but the code runs without error. Thanks.